# Continuously Auto-Scrolling ListView

Tags: android, listview, autoscroll

I have a `Listview` in Android. I want that the `Listview` continuously scrolls from top to bottom by itself. It should happen infinitely

And obviously I want to capture the click on any of the items of the `Listview`, post that the scroll will continue

Anybody having experience with such an implementation. Please help !!

Answer (score 5):

http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/msg/753a317a8a0adf03

To scroll automatically, you can use this: listView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);

```
private void scrollMyListViewToBottom() {
    myListView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // Select the last row so it will scroll into view...
            listView.smoothScrollToPosition(myListAdapter.getCount() - 1);
            // Just add something to scroll to the top ;-)
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Will this allow scrolling of the list without user touching the screen? My requirement is that the list keeps on scrolling by itself without any user interaction

Thanks

Comment: Can you help me with a small working example, I tried using the above snippet but the list straight away goes to the row where the last setselection was called. It doesn't do a autoscroll at all

Comment: ListView.smoothScrollToPosition(int i)